# Youtube embed issue with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, youtube

I am building a small static website on the popular BootStrap framework. I can't give a link unfortunately but essentially I have build a modal box which comes down on a button click with a YouTube video embedded into it.

It works fine but if you close the modal box then it disappears but leaves the YouTube video hovering over everything else with no way to get rid of it. This is on IE10.

Has anybody else tried embeddding videos into BootStrap Module boxes and have a solution for this?

Thanks in advance,

Jack

EDIT

OK, here is a snippet of code:

```
<a id="mediaVideo" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#video">Watch the interview</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="video" class="modal hide fade" style="color: #2a2a2a; width: 590px;" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
<h3 id="myModalLabel">This is the modal title</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<p>Small paragraph to describe the video</p>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/H542nLTTbu0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close Window</button>
<div class="btn-group">
<a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
Share This Video
<span class="caret"></span>
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" align="left">
<li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://www.google.com">Facebook</a></li>
<li><a href="http://twitter.com/share?text=This%20is%20the%20text&url=http://www.google.com">Twitter</a></li>
<li><a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://www.google.co.uk">Google+</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!--END MODAL-->
```

Comment: Code. You have to post it.

Comment: Right, give me a second and I'll put a snippet up

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working fine for me: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BenedictLewis/qzZ4a/). I am using the `<iframe>` option which is what is recommended when consulting the YouTube Embed API page at [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Manual_IFrame_Embeds).

Comment: It's IE10 which is having the issue, sorry I forgot to put that :) It's been a while since I posted anything

Comment: @JackWillDavis I have just tested the Fiddle on IE10 and it seems to work fine. Are you still having issues with it?